# How to grep capture a multiline pattern of a file in Perl

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have a file that looks something like this:

```
Random words go here
/attribute1
/attribute2
/attribute3="all*the*things*I'm*interested*in*are*inside*here**
and*it*goes*into*the*next*line.*blah*blah*blah*foo*foo*foo*foo*
bar*bar*bar*bar*random*words*go*here*until*the*end*of*the*sente
nce.*I*think*we*have*enough*words"
```

I want to grep the file for the line `\attribute3=` then I want to save the string found inside the quotation marks to a separate variable.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/perl
use warnings; use strict;
my $file = "data.txt";
open(my $fh, '<', $file) or die $!;
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    if ($line =~ /\/attribute3=/g){
        print $line . "\n";
    }
}
```

That's printing out `/attribute3="all*the*things*I'm*interested*in*are*inside*here**` but

I want `all*the*things*I'm*interested*in*are*inside*here**and*it*goes*into*the*next*line.*blah*blah*blah*foo*foo*foo*foo*bar*bar*bar*bar*random*words*go*here*until*the*end*of*the*sentence.*I*think*we*have*enough*words`.

So what I did next is:

```
#!/bin/perl
use warnings; use strict;
my $file = "data.txt";
open(my $fh, '<', $file) or die $!;
my $part_I_want;
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    if ($line =~ /\/attribute3=/g){
        $line =~ /^/\attribute3=\"(.*?)/;   # capture everything after the quotation mark
        $part_I_want .= $1;   # the capture group; save the stuff on line 1
        # keep adding to the string until we reach the closing quotation marks
        next (unless $line =~ /\"/){
             $part_I_want .= $_;    
        }
    }
}
```

The code above doesn't work. How do I grep capture a multiline pattern between two characters (in this case it's quotation marks)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my $str = do { local($/); <DATA> };
$str =~ /attribute3="([^"]*)"/;
$str = $1;
$str =~ s/\n/ /g;

__DATA__
Random words go here
/attribute1
/attribute2
/attribute3="all*the*things*I'm*interested*in*are*inside*here**
and*it*goes*into*the*next*line.*blah*blah*blah*foo*foo*foo*foo*
bar*bar*bar*bar*random*words*go*here*until*the*end*of*the*sente
nce.*I*think*we*have*enough*words"
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the entire file into a single variable and use `/attribute3=\"([^\"]*)\"/ms`

Comment: You don't need to escape the double quotes, and you don't need the `/ms` modifiers.

Comment: @glennjackman I assure you, you don't. We don't need `.` to match newlines, because we're not even using `.` in this pattern. [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers)

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it's incomplete. Rather than just telling someone what to do, it would be better to show the solution (with code).

Answer (score 1):

From the command line:

```
perl -n0e '/\/attribute3="(.*)"/s && print $1' foo.txt
```

This is basically what you had, but the `0` flag is the equivalent of `undef $/` within the code. From the man page:

> -0[octal/hexadecimal]
>
> specifies the input record separator ($/) as an octal or hexadecimal number.  If there are no digits, the null character is the separator.